# SQL Query for fusionchart needed, combine totals for team results

Tags: php, sql, fusioncharts

Currently i have a SQL database called members that has the following columns in it.

- memberID
- username
- team
- email
- target
- password
- type
- total

I am trying to get a chart to show two different color series of bars on a bar graph. One showing the Target and one showing the total but i want it by team.

Currently i have 337 students in 9 teams. Each student has their own target and the total is what they have actually raised. I would like to have chart combine all the similar teams together to show each team is doing.

Below is the current code which gives me the charts but only shows 1 student from each team not the cumulative of all students in the team.

```
    <?php
$rank = 0;
$sql = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM members WHERE type = 'student' ORDER BY  username ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) 
{
    echo "{\"value\":\"";
        $rank = $rank + 1;
        echo "$row->total\"},";
}
?>
            ]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "Target",
            "data": [
<?php
$rank = 0;
$sql = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM members WHERE type = 'student' ORDER BY  username ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) 
{
    echo "{\"value\":\"";
        $rank = $rank + 1;
        echo "$row->target\"},";
}
?>
```

What do i need to adjust to get this?
Sample of data is below

```
memberID    username     team   email   target  password    type    total
1191        Student 27   Team 9         3624                student 250
1280        Student 116  Team 7         986                 student 100
1392        Student 228  Team 4         1755                student 10
1318        Student 154  Team 8         2170                student 200
1282        Student 118  Team 7         986                 student 57
1458        Student 294  Team 6         620                 student 479
1174        Student 10   Team 5         2672                student 195
1390        Student 226  Team 4         1755                student 775
1446        Student 282  Team 3         1091                student 1090
1193        Student 29   Team 9         3624                student 3000
1346        Student 182  Team 8         2170                student 47
1187        Student 23   Team 9         3624                student 52
1232        Student 68   Team 7         986                 student 752
1241        Student 77   Team 7         986                 student 63
1234        Student 70   Team 7         986                 student 800
1236        Student 72   Team 7         986                 student 12
1391        Student 227  Team 4         1755                student 0
1479        Student 315  Team 6         620                 student 1
```